# Transferred apps to itunes connect, trying to update app, Potential Loss of Keychain Access

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I purchased an app from another developer and transferred it to my account.  I am now trying to publish an updated version with updated ad code.  I have tried a number of things, but I'm not sure what to do next.  I believe I am creating the profiles correctly.

I have tried the following combinations with no success:
Team Profile of current account and New Provisioning profile
Team Profile of current account and old provisioning profile
Team Profile of old account and New Provisioning profile
Team Profile of old account and old provisioning profile

I always get the "WARNING IMTS-9000: "The application identifier entitlement value has changed....This will result in a loss of keychain access."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but I had a similar problem. It turned out that the app DID get submitted, even though the error message/warning showed up. I had to take an extra step to get the app submitted though.

In iTunes Connect, on the page for that App, I had to scroll down to the Build section and click the (+) button to select which compiled app build I wanted to use during submission. After I did that, then I was able to submit my app for review.

Comment: Right. The app submission did not appear under the "Activity" tab, but it did get submitted.